# como hago para asignar palabras a numeros usando random en python?

Tags: python, string, random

## quisiera saber como tener en el output un str en vez de un numero.(sin usar listas o random.randint)

```
import random
prob=random.randrange(1,5)

1 = pedro
2 = maria
3 = juan
4 = luis

print (prob)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "python", line 6
>
> SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Comment: Hola Diego bienvenido a [es.so]. Usar una lista, tupla o diccionario sería lo normal... supongo que `random.choice` (`prob = random.choice(("pedro", "maria", "juan", "luis"))`) está también descartado por la misma razón ¿No? Se puede hacer con variables, `eval` y un casting a `str`, pero mucho sentido no tiene. ¿Por qué no puedes usar un contenedor?

Comment: Soy principiante y queria experimentar que cosas puedo hacer solo con randrange  . Si no conviene usar randrange, bueno supongo que aceptare las otras opciones.Solo queria quitarme esa duda .Bienvenidas sean las respuestas de todo tipo.

Comment: Ok, el uso de `randrange` no es ningún problema, lo que quizás si no es "conveniente"  es no usar un contenedor para almacenar las cadenas que son las posibles opciones a elegir. He creado una respuesta intentando explicar por qué falla tu código y dando varias opciones. Cualquier duda comenta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, el error se debe a que intentas realizar una asignación a un literal, en este caso un entero. Intentas definir una variable llamada `1` y asignarle la referencia a un objeto. Esto no es posible, es más, un identificador (nombre de variable) no puede ser un numero como es lógico, pero tampoco empezar por uno (`1a = "Hola"` por ejemplo es sintaxis inválida).

Además de esto, los literales de cadena han de estar entrecomillados siempre, en caso contrario serán interpretados como un identificador y no como una cadena:

> ```
> >>> s = hola  # Error si hola no está definido
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'hola' is not defined
>
> >>> s = "hola"    # Correcto
>
> >>> hola = 14
> >>> s = hola    # Asigna a s la referencia al objeto asociada a la variable hola
> >>> s
> 14
> ```

Dicho esto, para lo que quieres lo apropiado es usar algún contenedor, por ejemplo:

- Una lista/tupla e indexado:

  ```
  import random


  opciones = ("pedro", "maria", "juan", "luis")  
  opc = opciones[random.randrange(0, 4)]
  print(opc)
  ```
- Un diccionario:

  ```
  import random


  opciones = {1: "pedro", 2: "maria", 3: "juan", 4: "luis") 
  opc = opciones[random.randrange(1, 5)]
  print(opc)
  ```

Podemos usar directamente `random.choice` que obtiene un item de forma aleatoria (pseudoaleatoria realmente) de una secuencia:

```
import random


opciones = ("pedro", "maria", "juan", "luis") 
opc = random.choice(opciones)
print(opc)
```

Si no quieres usar un ningún iterable, podemos aún hacer algo. En la línea de  tu idea original, lo que aparentemente pretendías era elegir de forma aleatoria en base a su nombre entre una serie de variables ya definidas previamente y asociadas a cadenas. Esto es posible usando `eval`, aunque no es lo apropiado ni recomendable por norma general. Obviamente como ya se explicó, las variables no pueden ser un número:

```
import random


v1 = "pedro"
v2 = "maria"
v3 = "juan"
v4 = "luis"

opc = eval(f"v{random.randrange(1, 5)}")
print(opc)
```

`eval` acepta una cadena que debe ser código Python válido, la evaluá y retorna el resultado de su evaluación. En este caso recibe  una cadena que representa un identificador (`"v1"`, `"v2"`, `"v3"` o `"v4"`) y retorna el objeto asociado al mismo, la cadena con el nombre.

Se usa un literal de cadena para general el estamento. Los literales de cadena formateados están disponibles desde Python 3.6, se puede usar alternativamente por ejemplo:

```
opc = eval("v{}".format(random.randrange(1, 5)))
```

o bien:

```
opc = eval("v" + str(random.randrange(1, 5)))
```

> **Nota:** `random.randint` es realmente solo un alias para `random.randrange(start, stop+1)`, por lo que su única diferencia con `randrange` (aparte de no aceptar el tercer parámetro, `step`) es que el parámetro `stop` se incluye entre las posibles opciones:
>
> - **`random.randrange(1, 5)`** -> Un entero en el intervalo 1 <= n < 5. No incluye el 5.
> - **`random.randint(1, 5)`** -> Un entero en el intervalo 1 <= n <= 5. Se incluye el 5.